# Открытие формы

Tags: delphi

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы открывался не Form1, а Form3 (unit1  и unit3)?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать проще: заходим в меню Project -> Options и там выбираем в выпадающем списке название главной формы, кроме этого, можно ещё и в списке (Auto Create Forms - по умолчанию все формы там) порядок создания форм указать: первая в нём форма - главная, соответственно она первой и создаётся.

Answer (score 1):

Заходим в Project -> View source. Вместо

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

пишем

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
```